# Is hibernate executing additional update while persisting using @Convert annotation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When I'm trying to save a simple entity in hibernate with field marked with @Convert annotation insert is always followed by update with the same parameters as in insert.

Entity to save

```java
@Entity
public class Building {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Convert(converter = AddressConverter.class)
    private Address address;
    ...
```

Object that is converted to String

```java
public class Address {

    private String street;

    private String city;
    ...
```

Converter

```java
@Converter
class AddressConverter implements AttributeConverter<Address, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Address attribute) {
        return attribute.getStreet() + " " + attribute.getCity();
    }

    @Override
    public Address convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        String[] data = dbData.split(" ");
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setStreet(data[0]);
        address.setCity(data[1]);
        return address;
    }
}
```

It should work like that, and if it should, why? I don't see at first glance any reason to make this additional query.

Logs looks like this:

```java
18:52:14.959 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into building (address, id) values (?, ?) 
18:52:14.960 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [test-street test-city] 
18:52:14.961 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1] 
18:52:14.962 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - update building set address=? where id=? 
18:52:14.964 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [test-street test-city] 
18:52:14.964 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]
```

I've made proof, so you can check it here: https://gitlab.com/Piterowsky/demo-insert-update-convert-annotation/-/tree/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo

Comment: you need to implement `equals` and `hashCode` for `Address` class, otherwise HBN thinks entity is dirty after `persist`

Comment: yes, that was so obvious, thank you :)

Can you provide an answer so I can close this question?